# Keyboard service: capturing events outside of window

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, keyboard-events

I am aware that capturing keyboard events outside of the window is a security issue as it would enable any website to collect all your keystrokes with search history, credentials, ... But I am facing the following problem in a very legitimate scenario.

We have a highly flexible Angular framework and a very small piece of it can open dialogs with the press of a button. But by default when `CTRL` is pressed, instead of opening a dialog, the content is displayed in a new tab.

Now, to know wether or not `CTRL` is pressed, we keep track of the key up and down events. We store a boolean in a dictionary on key down and set it to false on keyup. To know wether or not `CTRL` is pressed, we simply lookup the keycode and return that value.

```
export class KeyboardService {

  private readonly _keys = new Map<Keyboard.Codes, boolean>();
  public readonly keyEvents = new Subject<KeyBoardEvent>();

  constructor() {
    fromEvent(window, 'keyup').subscribe((event) => {
      const e = event as unknown as KeyboardEvent;

      this._keys.set(e.code as Keyboard.Codes, false);
      this.keyEvents.next({
        origin: 'keyup',
        keyCode: e.code as Keyboard.Codes
      });
    });
    fromEvent(window, 'keydown').subscribe((event) => {
      const e = event as unknown as KeyboardEvent;

      this._keys.set(e.code as Keyboard.Codes, true);
      this.keyEvents.next({
        origin: 'keydown',
        keyCode: e.code as Keyboard.Codes
      });
    });
  }

  public get isCtrlDown(): boolean {
    return !!this._keys.get(Keyboard.Codes.ControlLeft) || !!this._keys.get(Keyboard.Codes.ControlRight);
  }
}
```

But the problem with this is the following scenario

1. The user for example has a dual monitor.
2. The user holds down control on the Angular webapp
3. With control pressed, he moves his mouse to the other monitor on a seperate app and focuses that window
4. He releases control. My webapp did not capture any event.
5. He goes back to our webapp
6. He presses a button that should open a dialog since no `CTRL` is pressed
7. A new tab is opened up.

Would there be a better way to know at any given time which keyboard keys are being pressed? The trick I use with the dictionary is an old one I learned from a C++ programmer which I assume is not limited by the OS to simply access everything you do. Modern browsers on the other hand are restricting (justified) almost everything.

Comment: I don't think that is even possible to do. As you already mentioned: A big security risk as the window is not focused anymore.

Comment: Would there be another way to know which keys are pressed? We need not to know WHEN it was pressed (inside or outside the app). Only the currently pressed keys when the user is inside the app. Because this is a major restriction when a user is entering the app with something already pressed. If that were simply to happen inside the session then we were allowed that information.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping track of keyboard events is indeed not an option inside an inactive browser window. However, your specific use-case of 'clicking a button while holding ctrl' does not require you to keep track of the ctrl key. The PointerEvent holds information on what 'special' keys are active:

```js
window.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  console.log(e.ctrlKey); // true if ctrl key is active
  console.log(e.shiftKey); // true if shift key is active
  console.log(e.altKey); // true if alt key is active
  console.log(e.metaKey); // true if the CMD/Windows key is active
});
```

In an Angular environment, this would look something like this:

```
@Component({
    template: '<button (click)="onClickHandler($event)">Click me</button>'
})
class MyButtonComponent {
    public onClickHandler(e) {
        console.log(e.ctrlKey); // true if ctrl key is active
        console.log(e.shiftKey); // true if shift key is active
        console.log(e.altKey); // true if alt key is active
        console.log(e.metaKey); // true if the CMD/Windows key is active
    }
}
```

Comment: How would this solve OP issue?

Comment: He wants to know if the user is holding the ctrl key while clicking a button. This is the way to do it.

Comment: That's not entirely correct, OP wants to capture these events *outside* of  the browser window

Comment: Please read the comments on the original question.

Comment: You are both correct. To be honest, my question did not put enough emphasis on it. The framework we have is highly flexible. Theoretically, the user might simply not even be clicking on something. We just have a piece of implementation that eithers opens a dialog or a new tab based on the `CTRL` value being present. So the 'button' is not a nescessity.

Comment: Although using the proposed solution by @yadejo we will probably find a detour to make it work.